# replacing existing PHP eCommerce website with WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to replace my existing eCommerce website which is in PHP with Woocommerce WordPress. I have got my theme, Dokan Plugin and many others but I dont know where do I get start? i have good experience on both but I want to keep my current site live while replacing WordPress with it and also I want to keep the URL structure same and replace my data such as products, vendors with WordPress. I have searched on google but did not find any tutorial to get me started I am looking forward to hear from you guys

Comment: If you want to keep your current site live, you should probably install the new wordpress version on a private instance and then push it to the server when you are finished.

Comment: how can I copy my php data to WordPress woocommerce?

Comment: This question has a huge scope. I would suggest making an attempt and split each individual issue into it's own individual question.